# How would I answer the following question about removable discontinuities?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

> $$f(x) = \frac{2x^2+2x-40}{x-4}$$
>
> Show that $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $4$ and determine the value for $f(4)$ that would make $f$ continuous at $4$.

I know what a removable discontinuity is but I don't quite understand how I could make a value for $f(4)$ that would lead to $f$ being continuous. Especially when $x = 4$ is undefined due to the denominator being zero.

Any help?

Comment: Divide the numerator by $x-4$. Can you divide polynomials?

Comment: Yes. I did what you said and got 2x + 10. Is this correct? If so, what am I supposed to do after? Thank you!

Comment: Use the definition  of continuity of a function at a point

Comment: For your function to be continuous  f(4) must be equal to the limit of the function at x=4

Comment: Now calculate the limit of the function at x=4

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Have you figured out the answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is twofold. We can show that there exists a removable discontinuity at $x=4$ by showing that the limit as $x\to4$ exists and that $f(4)$ is undefined. This is sometimes called a "hole."
$$f(x)=\frac{2x^2+2x-40}{x-4}=\frac{(2x+10)(x-4)}{(x-4)}=2x+10$$
We can simplify this to $f(x)=2x+10$ only if $x\ne4$. This is because if $x=4$, then $f(x)$ would be undefined as the denominator becomes $0$. We can calculate the limit now because $x$ will only approach $4$; it will not equal it. We can use direct substitution.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to4}(f(x))=2(4)+10=8+10=18$$
We have shown that the limit as $x\to4$ exists and that $f(4)$ is undefined, so there exists a removable discontinuity at $x=4$. Now, in order for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=4$, $f(4)$ would have to be equal to this limit as that is required for continuity. Thus, $f(4)$ would need to be equal to $18$. The problem is not asking us to change $f(x)$, only to state what $f(4)$ would need to be for it to be continuous there.

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=(2x2+2x−40x−4)/x-4. ---------- 1

2x^2+2x-40

2(x^2+x-20)
factorizing to 2(x+5)(x-4)  ---------- 2.

Substituting 2 in 1 gives.

2(x+5)(x-4)/(x-4)

equals to 2(x+5)

therefore it has a removable discontinuity at x=4.